# spring-web reactive package vs spring-webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I created a spring cloud gateway application via spring boot and it added two dependencies:

1. spring web
2. spring webflux

Inside of spring web jar, I also see a package: `org.springframework.http.server.reactive`

I had couple of question, why did it added both web and webflux dependency. Since cloud gateway is based off the web reactive framework, shoudn't it add just spring webflux dependency?

Also since spring web is based of the servlets, why does it contain the reactive package?

Any insights would help a lot in understanding these concepts.

Update:
Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>gateway</groupId>
  <artifactId>gateway-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gateway application</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your pomfile

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I have updated the same. Its pretty much standard of what I found in spring cloud gateway samples.